# как в scipy optimize поставить целочисленный шаг перебора?

Tags: python, scipy

День добрый.

Написал свою функцию, решил оптимизировать параметры, но не нашел где в optimize.differential_evolution проставляется шаг перебора параметров.
И как заставить перебор делать целочисленным?

```
result = optimize.differential_evolution(rsi2, ((2, 4), (1, 4)), )
print(result)
```

Comment: Добавьте еще желаемый результат.

Comment: Если я правильно понял исходники `PYTHON\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentialevolution.py` - выбрать "шаг перебора" нельзя...